# Only 4 point lights display in unity

Tags: unity, lighting

When ever I have more than 4 point lights in my scene, only 4 show up. Why does it do that? Is there anything I can do to show more than 4 at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendering lights is very GPU-costly operation. Forward rendering in particular.

You can increase the amount of lights Unity will render from the quality settings. If you are using a lot of dynamic lights in your game, you might want to consider switching to deferred lighting to make rendering lights a bit more optimized. If you are using static lights and objects, consider enabling light map baking.